# Passing Data Between UIViewController's With Category Conflict

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I have a `ViewController` class. It has a category `ViewController (Details)` which executes:

`(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender`

to open the details of an item.

When I add a new button to my `ViewController` class I want to pass some data as `NSArray *myData` to another controller, say, `SearchController`. However, my `prepareForSegue` would never execute because it is inside of `ViewController (Details)`. So adding `prepareForSegue` to `ViewController` seems to ignore it.

If I use working version of `prepareForSegue` inside `ViewController (Details)` that works for my `SearchController` but it does not see iVar `NSArray *myData` declared in `ViewController`. Ideally I'd not want to declare a new data var to be set in `ViewController (Details)` because it is irrelevant.

How to pass data from a button tap if `ViewController` does not execute `prepareForSegue` or `ViewController (Details)` does not see the data variable? Any recommendations?

Comment: Use something to store your data first like CoreData, Realm or Static reference, it doesn't matter. The important thing here is, if you use unidirectional flow for your data, probably you never get this problem again, because you don't need to pass data between classes, instead, you'll get data from a single source of truth always and that's it.

Comment: Please show code --- only the pertinent code --- from the VC and the category.

Comment: And @JanCássio is pretty much right: vcs should access the app's model themselves.  They must sometimes pass data, however, for example, when the user selects some aspect of the model in vcA, and vcB's job is to present details about it, it's reasonable and necessary for vcA to "pass data" to vcB insofar as it communicates a selection.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use categories until necessary. Instead you should use classes and composite pattern if you need to divide large classes on submodules. Categories override methods on classes and are loaded in undefined order, having multiple categories implementing the same method may result in very hard to debug issues. Categories don't allow you to store anything in instances without using associated objects which is ugly and more expense than ivars.